# kotlinで、Unresolved reference: textview

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Android studio3で、[リンク先内容](https://qiita.com/TomiGie/items/fb60a80780689b86dc59)を試しているのですが、

```
textview.text = greeting
```

「変数を使ってみる」に掲載されている上記内容を追加すると、

> Unresolved reference: textview

エラーとなり、ビルド失敗します

---

・下記エラー(あるいは警告？)も表示されているのですが、何か関係しているでしょうか？

> kotlin-stdlib-jre7 is deprecated. Please use kotlin-stdlib-jdk7
>   instead

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

layoutに存在するView要素のidで参照ができる機能は、Kotlin Android Extensionsによって実現されている機能です。

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

まずは以下のことを確認してください。

- app/build.gradleに`apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`が存在するか
- 対象となるActivityのlayout(xml)にあるTextViewに`android:id="@+id/textview"`が設定されているか
- Activityのソースコード(Kotlin)に`import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*`が書かれているか
  →対象となるActivityがMainActivity(activity_main.xml)の場合の例です

これらを確認した上で同じ問題が起きる場合、情報が足りていません。
質問に以下の情報を追記してください。

- Android Studioのバージョン
- Kotlinのバージョン
- app/build.gradle
- 対象Activityのソースコード(Kotlin)
- 対象Activityのlayoutファイル(xml)

Comment: 「import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*」を追記したら、無事ビルドできるようになりました。ちなみに「findViewById」に書き換えてもビルドできたのですが、このimportは「Kotlin Android拡張機能」を使う時のみ使用するのでしょうか？ Kotlinぽい書き方をしない場合はimportしなくても良い？　あるいはKotlinの場合はimportしてkotlinぽく書いた方が良い？？

Comment: リンク先の公式ドキュメントをお読みいただいたほうが早いと思いますが、このextensionsライブラリを適用した場合にimportができ、それによってView Bindingが可能になります。特定ライブラリの導入是非に関してはこのサイトでの範疇を超えるため、回答を控えさせて頂きますが、ご自身が`findViewById`を使って書くこと以上のメリットを感じられなければ、少なくともView Binding目的での導入は不要かと思います。

Comment: 通常、ライブラリは何かしらの課題を解決するために作られます。このextensionについても背景がリンク先に書かれていますので、ご覧になって頂くのが良いかと思います。 https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#background